# How to control XMPP XML

Tags: php, xml, client, xmpp

I am making a [XMPP PHP client](https://packagist.org/packages/norgul/xmpp-php) and currently while in testing phase I have made stanzas (i.e. presence) like this:

```
    const PRESENCE = <<<PRESENCE
<presence from="{from}" to="{to}" type="{type}" />
PRESENCE;

    const PRIORITY = <<<PRIORITY
<presence from="{from}">
    <priority>{priority}</priority>
</presence>
PRIORITY;
```

However while developing a library I wanted to do it somewhat programatically as I feel this approach looks like it's hardcoded even though I do parse it like this for example:

```
$preparedString = str_replace(
    ['{from}', '{priority}'],
    [$from, $priority],
    Xml::PRIORITY
);
```

So I ended up creating a `Presence` class which should hold all presence related methods and act as a sort of an XML builder, and it looks like this:

```
private $instance = null;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->instance = new \DOMDocument();
    $this->instance->formatOutput = true;
}

public function requestPresence(string $from, string $to, string $type = "subscribe")
{
    $presenceNode = $this->instance->createElement('presence');
    $presenceNode->setAttribute("from", $from);
    $presenceNode->setAttribute("to", $to);
    $presenceNode->setAttribute("type", $type);

    return $this->instance->saveXML($presenceNode);
}

public function setPriority(int $priority, string $from = null)
{
    $presenceNode = $this->instance->createElement('presence');
    if ($from)
        $presenceNode->setAttribute("from", $from);

    $priorityNode = $this->instance->createElement('priority');
    $priorityNode->appendChild($this->instance->createTextNode($priority));

    $presenceNode->appendChild($priorityNode);

    return $this->instance->saveXML($presenceNode);
}
```

But now I have some doubts as I have tripled my code and it was actually more readable before. I would like to keep it simple and effective and without code duplication, but I feel like I'm missing something here. Is there a more slick way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOMDocument is a more verbose interface for XML, you could use SimpleXML which will reduce the boiler plate code.

```
class XML {
    public static function requestPresence(string $from, string $to, string $type = "subscribe")
    {
        $instance = new SimpleXMLElement("<presence />");
        $instance["from"] = $from;
        $instance["to"] = $to;
        $instance["type"] = $type;

        return $instance->asXML();
    }

    public static function setPriority(int $priority, string $from = null)
    {
        $instance = new SimpleXMLElement("<presence />");
        if ($from)  {
            $instance["from"] = $from;
        }
        $instance->priority = $priority;

        return $instance->asXML();
    }
}
```

This assumes that they are two separate requirements and they are just utility functions rather than having to maintain any state.

If you need to build a document with more options then the following may be more useful...

```
class XML2 {
    private $instance = null;

    public function __construct()   {
        $this->instance = new SimpleXMLElement("<presence />");
    }

    public function requestPresence(string $from, string $to, string $type = "subscribe")
    {
        $this->instance["from"] = $from;
        $this->instance["to"] = $to;
        $this->instance["type"] = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setPriority(int $priority, string $from = null)
    {
        if ($from)  {
            $this->instance["from"] = $from;
        }
        $this->instance->priority = $priority;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getXML()    {
        return $this->instance->asXML();
    }
}
```

which called using...

```
echo  (new XML2())->requestPresence("from", "to", "type")
    ->setPriority(1)
    ->getXML();
```

creates...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<presence from="from" to="to" type="type"><priority>1</priority></presence>
```

Using DOMDocument or SimpleXML solutions will feel more bloated than your original version - but will provide a more robust solution which is more maintainable than relying on string handling.

Comment: I was thinking about second approach, however if I have the priority included, than I don't need `from`, `to` and `type`. Same about other stanzas, I can't use constructor in that way because I get XML's which server won't accept. Other looks good